# How to correctly disable/enable push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

Hello fellow developers.

I am trying to create an action using a UISwitch that allows users to disable/enable their push notifications. When I turn the switch off I don't receive the push notifications anymore. However if I try turning it back on I still do not receive it. Using Firebase as well.

Heres my App delegate code. I'll try to share relevant code but please feel free to request more pieces of code if you need.

PS: The code I am using for the switcher is actually from an answer I found on StackOverFlow.

```swift
// App delegate

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Registered for notifications", deviceToken)
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Registered with FCM with token:", fcmToken)
    }

  private func attemptRegisterForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        // APNS means Apple push notification services
        print("Attempting to register APNS...")

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self



        // user notification auth
        // all of this works for iOs 10+
        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, . badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to request auth:", error)
                return
            }

            if granted {
                print("Auth granted.")
            } else {
                print("Auth denied")
            }

        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    }
```

Here is the code I have in the settings view controller

```swift
   self.notificationSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)...

 @objc func action(sender: UISwitch) {

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey:"identifier")

        if(notificationSwitch.isOn) {
            print("Switch is on")
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        } else {

            print("Switch is off")
            UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try to remove device token from your Server/firebase as well in your switch action.

Comment: @charanjitsingh okay I’ll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs for [unregisterForRemoteNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623093-unregisterforremotenotifications?language=objc):

> You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a
>   new version of the app removes support for all types of remote
>   notifications. Users can temporarily prevent apps from receiving
>   remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings
>   app. Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.

The correct way (actually the way I have seen in the projects I have worked on) is to call an api and tell the backend that push notification should not be sent.

Comment: I wonder if I should just scratch the action then and remove it in general. I just thought it like be good user experience to give the user the option if they get annoyed in receiving notifications like comments, likes etc

Comment: It is indeed a good user experience. Every app has it. You just need to introduce a new api setting a flag backend for unregistering. The backend won't actually unregister the device token but it will check the flag and decide whether to send push notification to APNS or not.

Comment: Got it. I’ll work on that tomorrow thank you, I understand completely. Accepting answer.